# AndEngine Issue with Accelerometer in GameScene

Tags: box2d, andengine, accelerometer

I'm quite new to AndEngine and Android Development.

So here's my problem: I followed the Full Game Tutorial on this site unitl part 10:
http://www.matim-dev.com/full-game-tuto ... art-1.html
Maybe some of you know it. There we have a GameActivity extending the BaseGameActivity that is the main class of the game, and we also have a GameScene that extends the BaseGameActivity.

Now I want to implement for example the code from the PhysicsJumpExample.java from the AndEngine Examples just to see how it works.
Everything works fine except the part with the Acceleration, because as far as I know I need to extend the BaseGameActivity to do this: this.enableAccelerationSensor(this);

But how do I get the Acceleration to work in the GameScene too? I tried different approaches but nothing works :( The Sprite stays stuck on th screen.

Could anybody help / show me how to implement this in there?

EDIT:

Firstly I did some coding with the help of the AndEngine Exmaples and Tutorials. But it was only one activity that managed everything, so not very nice.

[https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12628048/Activity.java][1]

This works completely fine! But then I wanted to put it in a better arichtecture.
I found the Tutorial on this side and followed it until Chapter 10: http://www.matim-dev.com/full-game-tutorial---part-1.html 
And now I'm stuck with handling the Accelerometer:

```
  public class GameActivity extends BaseGameActivity implements IAccelerationListener
  {

    private Camera camera;

    public static GameActivity instance;

    public PhysicsWorld mPhysicsWorld;

    @Override
    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() 
    {
        camera = new Camera(0, 0, 768, 1280);
        EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(true, 
                                                        ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT_FIXED,
                                                        new RatioResolutionPolicy(768, 1280),                                                      
                                                        this.camera);

        engineOptions.getAudioOptions().setNeedsMusic(true).setNeedsSound(true);
        engineOptions.setWakeLockOptions(WakeLockOptions.SCREEN_ON);

        mPhysicsWorld = new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2(0, SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH), false); 

        return engineOptions;
    }
  }
```

I'm creating the PhysicsWorld there and also enable the Accelerometer there too.

I call this in my GameScene in the method `createPhysics()`, but somehow the `Object` I created stays stuck on the screen and isn't moving at all.

```
mPhysicsWorld = GameActivity.getSharedInstance().mPhysicsWorld;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You should take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/about).  Show us what you tried.

Comment: Does it help? I can't find a way to make it work and just getting NullPointerExceptions :/